# mysql syntax error: mysql not allowing certain characters to be processed

Tags: mysql-error-1064, mysql-real-escape-string

Am one step away from reading from a file and writing the data to a table in my database. Everything works correctly except when writing to the table in my database. This is the error message i get:

could not load. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'm not following you so that I can follow you back â™¡ )')' at line 1

This is my code:

```
$sql = mysql_connect("localhost", "root","root");
        mysql_select_db("Tweet_Corpora");
        if(!$sql){
            die("could not connect: " . mysql_error());
        }
        $file = fopen("/Applications/MAMP/bin/mamp/uploads/corpus/set_2.txt","r") or exit("Unable to open file!");
        while(!feof($file)){
            $string = fgets($file);
            $arr = (explode("\t", $string));
            $test = "INSERT INTO Display (tweet_id, raw_tweet) VALUES ('mysql_real_escape_string($arr[0])','mysql_real_escape_string($arr[1])')";
            $result = mysql_query($test);
            if(!$result){
                die("could not load. " . mysql_error());
            }
        }
```

What do i do? please help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to learn the difference between **strings** and **functions** in PHP

Comment: i don't get what you mean by that

Comment: That is your problem exactly. Please learn what a **function** is and how to use it.

Comment: I didn't mean that i don't know what the difference between the two is. I do know. I just didn't understand how it related to what i was asking. I managed to fixed and the working code is below. Thanks though

Answer (score -1):

Here is the working code with a bit of twist:

```
    $sql = mysql_connect("localhost", "root","root");
    mysql_select_db("Tweet_Corpora");
    if(!$sql){
        die("could not connect: " . mysql_error());
    }
    $file = fopen("/Applications/MAMP/bin/mamp/uploads/corpus/set_2.txt","r") or exit("Unable to open file!");
    while(!feof($file)){
        $string = fgets($file);
        $arr = (explode("\t", $string));
        $idd= mysql_real_escape_string($arr[0]);
        $tweet=mysql_real_escape_string($arr[1]);
        $test = "INSERT INTO Display (tweet_id, raw_tweet) VALUES ('".$idd."','".$tweet."')";
        $result = mysql_query($test);
        if(!$result){
            die("could not load. " . mysql_error());
        }
    }
```